# No agent found in pool Hosted which satisfies the specified demands: svn maven

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines

Using VSTS, and following [this step by step guide](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/integrations/subversion), I still get this error.
[image]

Am using the hosted pool, and have verified it has maven

[image]

What could be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That's actually the svn capability which is missing on the hosted agent. You might have to add a user capability and add a task to run a non-installed version of it and set the path on the current machine.
The other solution would be to install your build machine with all the tools you need

Comment: Hi Baywet, thank you for the answer. How would one go about adding svn to the hosted agent?

Comment: You can't install anything that will require touching registry or system's files (the user running agent doesn't have admin permissions). So adding the capability is done for the agent pills tab, select the hosted agent and then capabilities. And then you've got to script the usage of a self contained svn (I'm not very familiar with svn so I'm not sure how to do it)

Comment: The capability in my agent needed to do svn checkouts is name: svn and value: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe